# Windows 7 adding user to group "Użytkownicy pulpitu zdalnego" by batch script

Tags: windows, net

When running bat to add user to remote desktop users group from batch script

```
net localgroup "Użytkownicy pulpitu zdalnego" %user% /add
```

got error cause on output got "U┐ytkownicy pulpitu zdalnego" as group name (diffrent encoding?) and that give error that group don't exist.

Please advise

Comment: A general help might be to use simpler group names with full name in the description?

Comment: Try to save the batch file with notepad++ as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: @ JamesRyan - yes, but it's default name for rpd users in polish localization of win 7 :(

Comment: @ UserUser, try it, same thing :( error 1376 local group does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Solved

Save batch file as UTF-8 and change cmd codepage to UTF-8 with

```
chcp 65001
```

Answer (score 0):

`net.exe` does not support names longer than 20 characters.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324639

Comment: ok, so why it's work from comand line?

btw that link you provide is valid for :

 Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition (32-bit x86)
Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition (32-Bit x86)
Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition (32-bit x86)
Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Enterprise Edition (32-bit x86)
Microsoft Windows 2000 Professional Edition
Microsoft Windows 2000 Server
Microsoft Windows 2000 Advanced Server
Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition
Microsoft Windows XP Professional
Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 4.0 Developer Edition

not windows 7

Comment: You did not specify what Windows version you are using. Does it work with a simpler group name?